# Oracle parameter to a inner query

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I'm struggling with an Oracle query. I want to send a value to a inner query but I don't succeed. My query looks as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Pro u 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM PROLOG d
WHERE d.Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM PROLOG t
          WHERE t.Project = **u.Id** 
          AND t.Prodstatus IN    (5,40)))z ON (u.ID = z.Project)
WHERE u.Id = 22;
```

I want to replace the  **`u.Id`** with 22. The value 22 comes from Pro u table. Please give me some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass that value to sub query from `Pro` table, You can use `prolog` table value

```
SELECT * FROM Pro u 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM PROLOG d
WHERE d.Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM PROLOG t
          WHERE t.Project = d.Project 
          AND t.Prodstatus IN    (5,40)))z ON (u.ID = z.Project)
WHERE u.Id = 22;
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you can correlate a join to an inline view, however you can simplify your SQL statement to a simple outer join with a correlated predicate:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pro u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN prolog d 
    ON d.project = u.id
    AND d.Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) 
                    FROM prolog t
                    WHERE t.project = u.id
                    AND t.prodstatus IN (5,40))
WHERE u.id = 22;
```